# Implement a database saving sapproach that not including redundant

Tags: java, database, database-normalization

I am creating a library management system.

In my program, each user can borrow some books, then i should save that books information( as book name, book isbn , borrow date) into a table in my database.

Each user in my system has a primary key(ID), I want to use this approach:

When a user want to borrow books, that books information should save into a table in my database, But now, the `ID` number in my `userBooksTable` each row is duplicate.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand your question, could you provide a schema definition or visual representation of your schema? On a more general note, removing redundant can be achieved through [normalization of your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)

Comment: @atomman My main problem is finding a easy and safe way to save each user books records, and saving them into database, and can easy access them.

Comment: I would probably have a user table, book table and a borrowed table. The two first are pretty straight forward, containing just information about the users and books. While the borrowed table would just be the date, the foreignkey to the user borrowing, and the foreignkey to the book in question.

Comment: Look at what @Thomas posted as an answer. Same story, but may be easier to understand.

Comment: @atomman I understand from your comment that i should user `ID` for books and users, and my Borrowed table shouldn't has columns like `bookname` Or `bookISBN` and ... . Correct?

Comment: Correct. However, depending on your other needs, the ID for a book could be the ISBN if you dont have duplicate books in your library. But since it is a library I would guess your dataset have duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table layout might look similar to this:

```
books
-----
id (pk)
isbn
name

user
----
id (pk)
name
...

borrow
------
userId (pk, fk)
bookId (pk, fk)
date (pk)
```

So the main table would be `borrow` which contains the data which user borrowed which book at which date. All columns would be part of the primary key, since a user could borrow one book multiple times at different dates (provided it is returned in between ;) ).

You might need more information (e.g. if the user borrowed multiple copies at once or when the book was returned etc.), but I'll leave that for you.

Alternatively, you could use the isbn as the book's id, depending on whether it is unique or not, e.g. you could have a `bookinfo` table containing isbn, name etc. on the book and a `books` table containing data on one concrete copy of that book.

Comment: What means `pk` and `fk`?

Comment: @Sajjad pk = primary key, fk = foreign key